C++ custom allocators: in what circumstances would I be asked to return more than 1 unit?
I've written several memory allocator that couldn't allow the allocation of more than 1 unit of the specified type T, as apparently required by the Standard C++ library's collections that take allocator's.
Is there any official limit on which collections might ask for more than 1 unit, and under what conditions?
Failing that, is there any practical advice, basically for Windows and Linux, not for what is promised, but at least for what can be expected in the real world?
In principle that I could add low-performance code that supports such allocations, if I have no other choice, while hoping that the compiler would optimize away checks for allocation count due to the container calling it with a hard-coded "1".  I'm also thinking I should check the code and see what the current containers do, but my interest is a little broader than that: I'd like to make code likely to work going forward, or in past releases of STL, and so on.

For what is actually done: Probably only the containers like vector or deque, that hold a contiguous block of memory will use this feature. For make it likely to work going forward: Implement what the interface contains, because that is exactly what an interface is, it specifies the requirement you have to fullfil for the other code to work.

Why would you care about anything official if the allocator is your own thing?
Anyway, I'm curious enough to learn what you are trying to achieve with such a weird allocation, by one unit. What's your ultimate goal?

Why care if the allocator is your own thing -- Interoperability.  I'm writing a paper/article on allocation strategy, focusing on how an allocator can not only allocate fast, but allocate memory such that the app USING that memory is also faster.  I'm seeing a time savings of 10% in sorting vectors and building maps just one time, with memory I've allocated, more than is saved in the actual allocation.  I have a family of allocators, some which can serve arbitrary size requests and some that can't.  As a side quest I show them as std::allocator stand-ins, though that's not the main thrust.
